# PHP - cURL retornando erro "Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' object required: 'Session(...)'"

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde serão feitas várias automatizações (todas envio de formulários, relativamente simples) em sites externos utilizando o cURL.
Já obtive sucesso em pelo menos cinco casos, exceto no atual. Consigo efetuar login e capturar os cookies normalmente, mas ao abrir a página seguinte, é retornado o erro descrito no título.

Segue meu código:

Passo 01 - Efetuar login

```
$curl = curl_init('http://site.com.br/login.asp');
$fields = array(
'usuario'=>urlencode("usuario_login"),
'senha'=>urlencode("senha_login")
);
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&' ; }
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cookie.txt"); //GRAVO OS COOKIES EM UM ARQUIVO TXT
$resultado = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $resultado;
```

Até aqui tudo bem, é retornado a tela de boas-vindas. Então vou para a segunda página, onde existe o formulário para preencher.

Etapa 02 - Preencher o formuário

```
$curl = curl_init('http://site.com.br/formulario.asp');
$fields = array(
'campo_01'=>urlencode("dado_campo_01"),
'campo_02'=>urlencode("dado_campo_02"),
'campo_03'=>urlencode("dado_campo_03"),
);
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&' ; }
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cookie.txt"); //LEIO OS COOKIES DO ARQUIVO TXT
$resultado_final = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $resultado_final;
```

Então é retornado o cabeçalho e erro abaixo:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 
Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2015 20:27:46 GMT 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 
Content-Length: 321 
Content-Type: text/html 
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONID=EODOFMOBPPIFPLGDPPNCGMCL; path=/ Cache-control: private

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: 'Session(...)'
```

Algumas tentativas que já realizei:

Já tentei várias opções, estou a dois dias pesquisando em vários fóruns, e não importa o que eu faça ou quais CURLOPT eu use, o erro é sempre o mesmo. Inclusive, li toda documentação do cURL para ver se tinha algum CURLOPT que poderia ser útil.

Já tentei setar o cookie manualmente com CURLOPT_COOKIE com o valor que é retornado no header (ASPSESSIONID=EODOFMOBPPIFPLGDPPNCGMCL). Detalhe que o valor dessa session troca a cada requisição que faço a página.

Já tentei apenas exibir a página formulario.asp, sem efetuar POST (retirando os POSTSFIELDS).

Não sei se o erro está no cookie ou se o buraco é mais embaixo.
Olhando o código, vocês conseguem identificar algum erro que cometi?

---

Headers que defini

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Powered-By: ASP.NET';
$headers[] = 'Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0';
$headers[] = 'Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: pt-BR';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;';
$headers[] = 'Host: site.com.br';
$headers[] = 'Referer: http://site.com.br/formulario.asp';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: Você consegue fazer o que quer sem o curl, naquele mesmo site? Por exemplo, usando um browser qualquer? Pode ser apenas um erro no sites deles.

Comment: Consigo apenas no I.E em modo compatibilidade, nos demais (FF, Chrome e Safari) a pagina fica toda branca quando acesso o link do formulário.

Comment: Esse erro é do site - se você não for o dono do site, sugiro contatar-lhe and avisá-lo que o site dele tem um erro de VBScript quando faz o login. O cURL simplesmente retorna o que o site retorna. Se fosse um erro com cURL, teria retornaria um exceção do PHP mesmo.

Comment: No I.E. em modo compatibilidade consigo utilizar o site sem erro algum. Há alguma forma de fazer o cURL "simular" este modo de compatibilidade do I.E.?

Answer (score 1):

Eu tenho feito muito dessas automatizações ultimamente e fazendo scripts realmente simular interação humana. 
PHP+cURL é um pouco chato e há alguns detalhes que se deve atentar pois dependendo de como o servidor remoto analisa os pedidos, você precisa saber dessas sutilezas.
Olhando superficialmente seu script, aqui estão alguns ponto que você deveria notar:

### CookieJars

Você está certo quanto logar e criar uma sessão com cookiejar, no entanto as próximas requisições você deveria enviá-las com **CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE**, além do **CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR**, dessa forma os cookies de sessão serão reenviados se necessários, tal como o navegador. Então a primeira request você envia somente com **CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR** e as subsequentes com **CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR** e **CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE**.

### POST data

Outra sutileza aqui:
Se você passa para a opção **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS** um array, a requisição HTTP será enviada com um cabeçalho Content-Type como `multipart/form-data`.
Por outro lado, se você passa para essa opção (CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS) os parâmetros como [URL-encoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) dessa forma:

```
$post_params = http_build_query(array("param" => "value");
```

Então `Content-type` do pedido será `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Percebe? Dito isso, se o servidor avalia este header e não é exatamente o que ele espera, talvez ele (o servidor/aplicação) se negue responder o que você espera.
Percebi também que você está "encodando" individualmente cada parâmetro POST:

```
$fields = array(
    'campo_01'=>urlencode("dado_campo_01"),
//...
);
```

Isso não é necessário. Se você não usa [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) cURL vai cuidar disso pra você.

### Headers HTTP

Não abuse da sorte!

Sempre comece o script simulando exatamente (ou ao menos próximo) os headers necessários para a solicitação HTTP. Use o Chrome Developer Tools ou Firefox Dev Tools e cheque os os headers HTTP do pedido que você quer simular com PHP.
No mínimo deveria haver ao menos um cabeçalho informando o User-Agent.
Muitas vezes a aplicação verifica o `User-Agent` e, também, o header `Referer`.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, segui suas recomendações e o erro persiste.

CookieJar - Fiz exatamente conforme recomendou
POSTDATA - utilizei o http_build_query.
Headers - utilizando o Chrome Dev Tools (e também pelo IE, já que o site só funciona no IE), consegui visualizar os headers da página, sendo assim, defini as seguintes opções: (editarei minha pergunta por aqui nos comentários excedeu o limite de caracteres)